# Prevent Alexa Skill Timeout on Lock Screen

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I’ve created an Alexa skill using Python sdk and lambda as endpoint. Lambda retrieves some data from API and Alexa reads data. Sometimes data read takes 2-3 minutes. Everything works fine on my echo but on Alexa mobile app if the screen dims then locks Alexa shuts off. I know I can increase screen lock timeout on mobile but is there anything on Alexa app or SDK to prevent screen timeout while a response is given? Somehow this is done for other audio but I’m guessing it’s because it plays a audio file. Thanks

Comment: Can you share a sample JSON response from your skill? Looking to see what mechanism you're using to play the audio file.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, extending the session timeout duration is not a supported feature of Alexa Skills Kit. You will need to take a look at your back-end architecture to see where latency could be improved.

That being said, a possible workaround could be by utilizing the Progressive Response API to improve the perceived latency experienced by providing some interstitial content for Alexa to play while waiting for your skill's full response. For more information, please see the documentation here:

https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/send-the-user-a-progressive-response.html

https://developer.amazon.com/blogs/alexa/post/f952eca8-7f6f-4490-85d8-a805b50f6d25/alexa-skill-recipe-improving-the-perceived-latency-of-api-calls-using-the-progressive-response-api

https://github.com/alexa/alexa-cookbook/tree/master/feature-demos/skill-demo-progressive-response